# Spring Boot native compilation fails with GraalVM 21

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graalvm

Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.svm.util.ModuleSupport$ModuleSupportError: open of packages from module org.graalvm.polyglot to ALL-UNNAMED failed. No module named org.graalvm.polyglot in boot layer.

```
<buildpacks>
    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/graalvm</buildpack>
    <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
</buildpacks>
<env>
    <BP_JVM_VERSION>21.0.0</BP_JVM_VERSION>
    <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
</env>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues building with Java 21, and it was because Paketo does not include buildpacks for Java 21 (see https://paketo.io/docs/howto/java/#jvm-default-version). So I had to specify the following buildpacks for the plugin:

- `gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:10.4.2` (according to https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/releases)
- `gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image`

As you already have, `BP_JVM_VERSION` must be `21.0.0`, and `BP_NATIVE_IMAGE` must be `true`.

So the maven configuration should look like:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <buildpacks>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:10.4.2</buildpack>
                        </buildpacks>
                        <env>
                            <BP_JVM_VERSION>21.0.0</BP_JVM_VERSION>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This is the task configuration for Gradle in case it helps someone:

```
tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {
    
    buildpacks = ['gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image', 'gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica:10.4.2']
    environment['BP_NATIVE_IMAGE'] = 'true'
    environment['BP_JVM_VERSION'] = '21.0.0'
    //environment['BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS'] = '--verbose'
}
```